# Popup to propagate upvote to question when upvoting an answer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, voting, upvotes

When I find an answer that is useful for me, I like to upvote it. In the same way, I like to upvote the question too, because it made it possible for that answer to be written in the first place.

However, I have to scroll the page up each time. I think that this could be improved, and that the fix could finally lead to benefits for the entire community.

So it would be nice if, when voting an answer, a popup appears asking the user if he wants to upvote the question too.

This way, votes on questions should increase, thus allowing a better reward to be given to question authors, which should lead (ideally) to better questions.

This is how I would phrase it:

> Thanks for your feedback! Would you like to upvote the question too?

I wouldn't use too much words, because they would just involve more cognitive-load for users who already use it as a time-saver.

Comment: Pop-ups can be annoying when you don't want to use them. In my experience, wanting to upvote an answer without upvoting the question is common enough that it would become annoying.

Comment: @duplode C'mon, non-obtrusive prompts/alerts have been with us for several years, SO uses them without any issues.

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba Obtrusiveness is not a binary state. Given that the purpose of a pop-up is distracting the user from what they are currently doing, any pop-up is potentially obtrusive. Whether any specific pop-up is in fact obtrusive depends not only on how it is designed, but also on how often it shows up, and how relevant whatever it is they point to actually is.

Comment: @duplode Please consider following: Is the message you are shown when downvoting a wrong answer obtrusive? && How often you upvote an answer? Once a day. So once a day you would get to see a subtle text message asking you to consider upvoting also the answer. How obtrusive is that? :)

Answer (score 14):

I don't agree with this feature request, here is why:

1. Pop-ups can be very annoying if they appear each time someone upvotes.
2. It's not true to assume that upvoting an answer leads to upvoting the question, they are two separated things - a bad question can have a good answer and vice-versa.

Comment: None of your sub-answers does address the question. 1) This is *<current year>* and non-obtrusive alerts have been with us for several years already. SO uses them in several other situations. (Like when you downvoted the question.) Unless you want to dispute that this is not a valid point. 2) No one is suggesting "auto-upvote so I have to go and remove the upvote." I.e. again, unless you want to dispute that this is not a valid point.

Comment: I don’t agree with this answer. I had a question that originally had two answers. One answer was removed due to not being correct. But I only had one vote yet the accepted answer two votes. I think many many users of SO remember to vote answers and forget to upvote the question.

Answer (score 2):

For low quality questions, it is not uncommon for those to obtain answers which are upvoted, but primarily as a signal of resolution to a problem which may be based on false premises or just be so poorly researched that a simple search would have brought them to the answer.
In such cases, it is understandable that people do not want to leave it unanswered, even though its usefulness becomes even more subjective at the time of asking. It can get upvotes anyway because it has served its usefulness at that moment.
Just because a question attracted an answer considered useful does not automatically mean that the question itself is useful.

Now, what really *does* make a question useful is for it to be the match for someone else's problem that they were looking for. If it comes up on searches, they will find the answers and the question will benefit from it with the extra attention. This, if it happens, is when the upvotes start flowing naturally, without the need for automatic votes or pesky pop-ups.
[How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467995/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-rust) is one of the many examples of this. It's a one-sentence zero-effort question which started receiving downvotes in its early iterations, but over time it started receiving upvotes as it became a *de facto* source for knowing which bitwise operations are available in Rust.

To put it shortly: not only is the reasoning to this request flawed, there is also no need for such mechanism.