# Reputation points for the questioner whose answer gets voted up

Tags: support, feature-request, duplicate-questions, voting, asking-questions

When an answer gets voted up, the person who has asked the question should get reputation points added, because at the core of **Stack Overflow** it is the huge cache of questions by the questioner which get the community to come searching for an existing answer to their task.

**Pros**:

- This further bolsters the environment of question asking.
- It also gets questioner feeling satisfied every time someone is helped by an answer posted against their question.
- Not to mention the questioner will get free reputation points as a reward for posting a question which continuously is helping other programmers/users.
- This feature will also help reduce 'question duplication' by developing a 'human psychology' based watch system *(where questioners do not want their reputation points to be annexed by someone else)*, thus users who originally posted the question will actively and proactively search and tag the duplicate questions.
- This feature will get questioners to post better and better quality question to make the questions convey more information more precisely and attract the best answers.

**Cons**:

- Wile E. Coyote will never catch the Road Runner.

Comment: I like this proposal. a good incentive to attract more and more users to our already *overflowing community.

Comment: Asking needs no additional incentives. That premise is rather absurd. And askers are already satisfied when they get answers, and already get rewarded when they accept answers. Not much makes sense in this FR.

Comment: "Not giving enough free rep points" is not a problem SO has. This fixes nothing and introduces new problems.

Comment: @yivi Are questions not the primary reason for which millions of people visit the *overflow network, why do they not go to https://dev.to, etc? ... So IMHO asking question does need incentives.

Comment: @yivi When you think like a hammer every things looks like a nail, is it? It is not only about  "fixes". Continues improvement is what keeps *overflow on the cutting edge.

Comment: People come here for the answers ;)

Comment: People come here to ask questions. They do not need incentive to ask questions. The incentive is to get answers.

Comment: There used to be a [popup telling people that questions need love too](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/06/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/), I'm assuming that's still a thing?

Comment: @ivarni "People come here to ask questions" -> Without a doubt. But what results in those answers? > The Questions

Comment: @ivarni I have never seen this pop-up. 0_o

Comment: Do you seriously believe we have a problem of "not enough people asking questions"?

Comment: @yivi "a problem" -> you seem to have miss-understood my proposal completely. The proposal it to attract even more people to ask questions in addition to continuously rewarding the people who did ask those question.

Comment: We don't need more people asking more questions. We need less people asking crappy questions, and more people asking quality questions. You FR goes dead on against this objective.

Comment: @yivi i have added another item in the 'pros', just for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but putting it there doesn't make it true. Your FR does nothing to encourage quality questions. We already have a mechanism for that. It is called "voting". And it is so weak against the already existing incentive of "I want an answer right now!", that does very little against the growing tide of crappy questions. Your FR would just aggravate the problem, on top of giving "free" rep to people who don't necessarily deserve it. It doesn't follow that because an answer is good the question is good as well.

Comment: @yivi Thank you for your input, even if you do not like my Feature Request.

Comment: @SymfonyUser did you think about what your proposal would do to sock puppets? How easy it would be to post a Q, answer it with other account(s), then throw upvotes left right and center to get MASSIVE amount of reps. Yes the mods would catch these quickly... But do we want to overwork them even MORE?

Comment: @Zuhayer if I go and edit "this system will also give us peace on Earth".... Doesn't mean it will. Any clue WHY it would encourage better questions instead of more questions period? Since there will be more incentive to questions, we run at a risk of just getting more questions without ANY regards for quality... I personally (and most other commenters) see it as doing the exact opposite of your edit

Comment: see also: [Why don't questions get that much upvote love?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359703/839601)

Comment: Some of the answers make sense and have correctly countered the question.However,the question itself is important and I don't understand why it has so many downvotes.

Answer (score 31):

**Cons:**

- It will reward people for asking low-quality questions that just so happened to get a good answer.
- It would be "double-dipping", since askers already get reputation from upvotes to good questions, *and* from accepting the answer that helped them the most.
- Asking a question *and getting an answer to it* is its own reward.

[image: "Okay, wise guys, you always wanted me to catch him...now what do I do?" in signs held up by Wile E. Coyote, referring to the Road Runner]
<sub>This is a screenshot taken from an optical disc, television broadcast, web page, computer software or streaming media broadcast. Copyright holder: Warner Bros., Fair use, https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=24541169</sub>

**See Also:**

- [Why would you NOT upvote the question that you are bothering to answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351716)
- [Answering questions should auto-upvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265919)
- [Should providing an answer automatically count as an upvote to a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355630)
- [Should acceptance of an answer carry an automatic upvote from the questioner?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269928)
- [Popup to propagate upvote to question when upvoting an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338958)
- [Shouldn't most questions get at least as many upvotes as their most popular answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262440)

Comment: Point 1 -> This can be resolved. For example there could be a community based system which would allow a question to get these reputation points. Or someone can suggest an even better solution.

Comment: Point 2 -> in my 5 years using stack over flow I have only recently up-voting good question. That does not mean that the help I got from those earlier 4 years of questions and answers was of low quality. For me it only means I had not not realized the value of a precisely asked question

Comment: @SymfonyUser More complexity for a system that has zero benefits?

Comment: @AndrewLi 'zero benefits?' .. I would, with the most humble of intentions, suggest to read my proposal again from a mind set of 'continues improvement'.

Comment: @SymfonyUser Encouraging, as pointed out by Cody, low-quality questions that have good answers is not a pro at all. I don't see how that could translate to the asker to improve their question if they get rewarded?

Comment: @AndrewLi I have already responded to this worry above. "" -> "" Point 1 -> This can be resolved. For example there could be a community based system which would allow a question to get these reputation points. Or someone more intelligent can suggest an even better solution.

Comment: @SymfonyUser I know, and thus again, why more complexity for a system that hasn't shown any foreseeable benefit? And you just proved my point with the need of an extra system for validating points, a horrible waste of resources.

Comment: @AndrewLi I understand when you say 'extra system for validating points'. Thank you for your input. I would still suggest that you might not bee seeing the foreseeable benefits which might be tangible, but there are more types of benefits too.

Comment: @SymfonyUser As said by other commenters and Cody, the pros in your initial request don't make sense. Questions don't need to be encouraged, especially bad ones, and we shouldn't be encouraging bad content. I'm not sure how this reduces duplication, if anything it encourages it, because there's a lot of people willing to post dupe answers, and a lot more willing to upvote them. This also won't logically make anyone post better if they just get rewarded for something they probably didn't write (the answer). What others?

Comment: I don't understand the very first comment here on how point 1 can be resolved: *"For example there could be a community based system which would allow a question to get these reputation points."* What would that system do, and how would it solve the problem of low-quality questions earning the asker reputation?

Comment: @Cody I think the OP had in mind a 'review queue'of some kind so that the community can review ALL questions(damn it's hard to type that without laughing) to determine if they are 'good enough' to get the rep from answers' upvotes.

Comment: Said system would have the same flaws that the current system does.

Answer (score 8):

Let's examine the list of "pros" for this idea:

> This further bolsters the environment of question asking.

Let's assume for the moment that "the environment of question asking" is something that actually needs "bolstering". Even though the site is far from running out of questions being asked, let's ignore that and focus just on that idea.

I would say that it doesn't do anything about "the environment of question asking". Of all the activities people do to get reputation on SO, asking questions *is not one of them.* People ask questions because they need an answer. Giving them rep for answers that get upvoted will not cause people to ask more questions, because it will not magically put them in a position where they *need more questions answered*.

Now, you might say that people could have more questions that they need answering if they just make some up. And if you give them more of a reputation incentive, then people will be lining up to invent scenarios and so forth to ask questions about.

But the primary purpose of this site is to solve *practical problems* people have. Making up questions, inventing things to ask about is not solving practical problems.

So, to the extent that this idea "bolsters the environment of question asking", it would only do so in a *negative* way.

> It also gets questioner feeling satisfied every time someone is helped by an answer posted against their question.

In theory, sure. So what?

The asker already gets satisfaction by knowing that someone liked their question enough to upvote it. And they already get their primary satisfaction by someone solving their problem.

Do we really need the asker to "feel satisfied" when someone likes an answer? One that they, quite frankly, had very little to do with?

> Not to mention the questioner will get free reputation points as a reward for posting a question which continuously is helping other programmers/users.

Again, so what?

Reputation exists to encourage good behavior. Good questions are rewarded with upvotes. Good answers are encouraged with upvotes and acceptance. How does giving "free reputation points" encourage good questions?

After all, not-very-good questions often have answers that get upvoted. Why should we reward people for mediocrity?

> This feature will also help reduce 'question duplication' by developing a 'human psychology' based watch system *(where questioners do not want their reputation points to be annexed by someone else)*, thus users who originally posted the question will actively and proactively search and tag the duplicate questions.

No, they won't.

Oh sure, if you can create more links to your question, then there's a better chance of scoring rep. But that's true as of right now; if it's a good question and its a dupe-target, there's a good chance of scoring a question upvote.

But has that incentive caused a rash of people to actively search for duplicates to their questions? No.

Nor will this idea.

> This feature will get questioners to post better and better quality question to make the questions convey more information more precisely and attract the best answers.

No, it will not. It will encourage mediocrity. It will encourage askers to post *anything* they can get away with. After all, pretty much any answer will score an upvote or two. So even a slightly downvoted question will still likely yield an overall positive reputation result.

Now, you'll probably say that we can find ways to avoid that by adding more rules. Use a review system to decide if a question is worthy of answer-upvote-rep. Or if the question is negatively voted, then they don't get answer-upvote-rep. Or whatever.

But that's merely proof that the idea is poor. A good idea is a *simple* one. If you have to add a bunch of patch fixes and complexity to it just to make it work, then it's not a good idea.

Upvote a post, the person who posted it gets rep. That's a simple idea. And a good one.

Answer (score -5):

I think it is not a bad idea.

1. A question which has a really good answer, maybe it is not so bad, even if it is downvoted. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42384565/1783163))
2. It would serve as a compensation: by asking the question which made a highly upvoted answer possible, also the OP served the community, even if his question was voted down.
3. On the main sites, there is a tendency that people tends to vote down unfairly questions on many reasons. Having such a modification in the system would have a compensating effect for such posts.
4. On the meta sites, there is a tendency that people votes question downs thinking that it says "no". But it says some very different, it says: "this question is not useful". Saying "no" means that you vote the "no" answer up. It is possible, that an idea is bad, thus the "no" answer is correct, but making it clear is *useful*. In this cases, the question with the rejecting answer should be voted up. Many of our meta voters can't or won't understand it.

I think the best would be if some - maybe 5 - upvote to the most upvoted answers would mean a community upvote also to the question.

Comment: WRT point 3: People also downvote fairly a lot of the time - wouldn’t this also offset perfectly reasonable downvotes for the same reason that it offsets unfair downvotes?

Comment: Also, check the FAQ - Meta voting on feature requests  definitely indicates agreement or disagreement. Besides, how is saying “this feature request is not useful” different than indicating disagreement?

Comment: @EJoshuaS In this case, not the voting custom has adapted to the rules, but the rules to the custom. But it was, it is a bad custom. After many years SE experience, I think my opinion is not groundless saying, that behind this custom is a generally antagonistic, oppressive community attitude, which is highly unfortunate.

Comment: @EJoshuaS In the rare case when a good question gets only crap answers, the mods typically intervene with a 10- protection or lock. An upvoted question getting only deeply downvoted answers is *very* rare. A downvoted question getting upvoted answers is common.